# Can't install JUnit into Netbeans 8 offline

Tags: netbeans, junit4

I've downloaded the 2 NBM's for JUnit.  In Netbeans 8 I'm using the Tools->Plugins->Downloaded window and have added the pertinent NMBs.  They are both check-marked and when I press "Install" Netbeans then pops open a dialog that says (approximately) "Installer will download, verify, then install the selected modules".  It then does attempt to use the Internet to download - and fails.  This machine has no access to the Internet (hence the offline approach).

Have I not downloaded the proper NBMs (they were ZIP files and I renamed them to NBM - read that was the thing to do)?  Is there some other piece that I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the .external file contrains URL to files to be downloaded from an active internet connection.

For example, in my case (netbeans 8.0) org-netbeans-libs-junit4.nbm contains the file

```
/netbeans/modules/ext/junit-4.10.jar.external
```

which contents is

```
CRC:3480621823
SIZE:253160
URL:http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.10/junit-4.10.jar
URL:m2:/junit:junit:4.10:jar
```

if you need to perform an offline installation of the plugins in netbeans you need to transform the .nbm  files : replace the .external in .nbm file by the file refenced by URL.

In my case :

1) donwload  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.10/junit-4.10.jar

2) in the org-netbeans-libs-junit4.nbm, replace

```
/netbeans/modules/ext/junit-4.10.jar.external
```

by the donwloaded file at this location in the .nbm archive

```
/netbeans/modules/ext/junit-4.10.jar
```

3) save the transformed archive, 
4) do the same for the other nbm archive
5) you can add and install the the .nbm  files as plugin in Netbeans

remarks :

in `org-netbeans-libs-junit4.nbm, I had to replace

```
/netbeans/modules/ext/junit-4.10.jar.external
```

in `/netbeans/modules/ext/junit-4.10.jar.external, I had to replace

```
/netbeans/modules/ext/junit-3.8.2.jar.external
/netbeans/docs/junit-3.8.2-api.zip.external
/netbeans/docs/junit-4.10-javadoc.jar.external
/netbeans/docs/junit-4.10-sources.jar.external
```

Comment: If "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.10/junit-4.10.jar" was changed to "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.10/junit-4.10.jar". Then it would probably work too. Its all this HTTP  to HTTPS stuff causing the issues.